# Pytest patch field's default attribute for inherited django model

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, pytest

I have the following model in common/models.py:

```py
from django.db import models
from uuid import uuid4

class BaseModel(models.Model):
    guid = models.UUIDField(unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)

    class Meta:
       abstract = True
```

In app/models.py I have the following:

```py
from django.db import models
from common.models import BaseModel

class Entity(BaseModel):
   name = models.CharField()
```

In tests I tried to patch `uuid4` in the following ways:

```py
def test_model_create(mocker):
   # Given
   mock_guid = mocker.patch("uuid.uuid4", return_value="some-guid")

   # When
   entity = Entity.objects.create(name="test_name")

   # Then
   mock_guid.assert_called_once()
   assert "some-guid" == entity.guid
```

`mock_guid.assert_called_once()` returns not called. What can be the issue here?

Comment: What about `mocker.patch("common.models.uuid.uuid4", …)`?

Comment: @hoefling I tried it in the first place. But, it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that `guid = models.UUIDField(unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)` references the `uuid.uuid4` function directly at parsing time. When you set up your mock, it's too late to replace this pointer.

Changing it to something like `guid = models.UUIDField(unique=True, default=lambda: uuid.uuid4(), editable=False)` should fix your issue, because the value is returned at runtime, and your mock will be setup properly before the function is referenced and called.

Comment: I used function instead of lambda. Because after changing field attribute migration required and during migration it fails with "cannot serialize lambda function". So, I changed it.